# get ast from python object in interpreter

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I am building an application for which I would like a naive user to define a simple function. I would then like to take this function and convert it into an abstract syntax tree. This should also work during an interactive session (i.e using the interpreter). Here's what I have tried so far in the interpreter:

- `dill.source.getsource` method
- `inspect.getsource`method
- accessing the function object's `__code__` attribute

The first two methods are problematic since they need for the function object to be written in a physical file somewhere in the system. The third one only gave me a byte code version of the code, not useable in `ast.parse` method.

I am also open to converting a python object directly to abstract syntax but this seems to go [against how ast's are supposed to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43575099/convert-python-objects-to-python-ast-nodes).

I really need to be able to get an ast from my python object in a regular (not ipython) interpreter. How can I do this?

**EDIT**

Heres how my "naive user" would interact with my custom library through the interpreter:

```
>>> import MyLib
>>> def f(x): return x**2
>>> f = MyLib.FunctionAST(f) #FunctionAST will handld the conversion to abstract syntax
```

Comment: Do users give you a function object or source code? If it's the former, how do they do this without you being able to access the source?

Comment: users write out the function and instantiate a class I am creating by passing in the function object. Please see edit to original question for an example.

Comment: The search term for this is "decompile" - if the function's source code is not available then you must decompile its bytecode.

Comment: Where's `decompile`? I can't find it anywhere?? Could you give an example?

Comment: `ast.dump(ast.parse(inspect.getsource(f)))` does work when using `ipython`. It doesn't work in normal python shell because `linecache.cache` is empty there. If you expect the user to interact in a shell, doesn't it make more sense to use an interactive one?

Comment: I'd like to make this as flexible as possible... I prefer not to force the user to use any particular shell, but have this work in any python shell. Is there a clean way to force use of ipython?

Comment: I tried `dill.source.getsource` in a python shell, and it works as expected: `ast.dump(ast.parse(dill.source.getsource(f)))`. Apparently, `inspect.getsource` doesn't work for objects which are defined interactively. [Reference](https://riptutorial.com/python/example/23814/display-the-source-code-of-an-object#undefined) and [python bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue12920)

Comment: `dill.source.getsource` does not work for me and returns `OSError: could not extract source code`. Are you sure you're not using ipython? What version of `dill` are you using?

Comment: I am using python `3.6.8` and `dill==0.3.1.1`. And, yes I am sure that I am in python shell because I tested it again. Check [here](https://imgur.com/a/l08S9Cj).

Comment: The interpreter destroys the AST as soon as it uses it to generate the bytecode.  Your request, as stated, is impossible.

Comment: Why not just ask the user to provide a string with the source code, instead of the actual function object?